# How can I use the Text-GameObject in my C#-Script in Unity3d. Where can I find the assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to assign a Text-GameObject to a Property in a C#-Script (Something like in SampelButton.cs - [creating-scroll-lists-at-run-time](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/creating-scroll-lists-at-run-time?playlist=17111)).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class SampleButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text typeLabel;
}
```

Unfortunatly my Visual Studio tells me that it is missing an assemby. I think I need an assembly reference to UnityEngine.UI. But where kann I find the dll? I am using unity 5.1 (Windows).

**EDIT:**
Without the line `using UnityEngine.UI;` I get the following Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

With the line `using UnityEngine.UI;` I get the following Error:

```
The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a DLL. Try syncing your project again.

Comment: Do you get compile errors when trying to run the game in Unity? Visual Studio tends to glitch out a lot with Unity.

Comment: Text is defined in UnityEngine.UI namespace, and the assembly is UnityEngine.dll.

Answer (score 2):

I've found something like a workaround.

In my Project folder there is the **Library/** folder. It holds some dll's (UnityEngine.dll, UnityEngine.UI.dll, ...). If I delete the folder, it will be recreated at the next start of my project.

If I forget to delete the **Library/** folder. I get a state with some missing dlls.

If someone has an explanation of that behaviour. He will get the points.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me from an awful headache. I removed all references from the project in visual studio, deleted the library folder and now it builds perfectly!